# Multiple RewriteRules for single RewriteCond in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following command in my .htaccess

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)-([a-z]+) %2/$1.$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)-([0-9]+)([a-z]) %2/$1$3.$2 [L]
```

%2 is not working in second and later lines.
Can I define any variable for %2 and use it in all RewriteRule commands?
Following command works

```
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*?)-([a-z]+) %2/$1.$2 [L]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*?)-([0-9]+)([a-z]) %2/$1$3.$2 [L]
```

But I want use %2 for multiple rule line without duplicating condition.

Comment: you might view 4 tricks listed here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276207/5064633

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The variable must be saved as an Apache var, then that can be used without repeated conditions.

Saving in Apache variables are shown in second line. Usage of saved vars in 3th and 4th lines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [E=Wa:%1,E=Wb:%2]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-([a-z]+) %{ENV:Wb}/$1.%{ENV:Wb} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-([0-9]+)([a-z]) %{ENV:Wb}/$1$3.$2 [L]
```

Comment: exactly what I needed Hussain!

Comment: You can use Wb variable Where you want virtual subdomain.

Answer (score 73):

You can use the RewriteRule flag `S|skip` to tie multiples RewriteRules to a single RewriteCond (or to a set of RewriteConds). Here is an example that applies one Cond to three Rules:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www.mydomain.com$
# skip rules if NOT within domain - only way to tie multiple rules to one cond
RewriteRule  .?  -  [S=3]
RewriteRule  ^path1(/.*)$  /otherpath1$1
RewriteRule  ^path2(/.*)$  /otherpath2$1
RewriteRule  ^path3(/.*)$  /otherpath3$1
```

To change an existing Cond to work for multiple Rules you have to:

- Negate the condition (prepend it with !)
- If you have multiple RewriteConds: 
  Change logical ANDs in the Conds to ORs and vice versa.
- Add a skipping rewrite rule in front of all rules that you want to tie to the condition(s). Set the S parameter to the number of Rule lines to be skipped.

Please be aware that it is not possible to use any backreferences that point back to the RewriteCond (like %1) in the skipped Rules. These are only accessible in the skipping RewriteRule.

Comment: This solves only the logic part, not the backreferences part, as the `RewriteCond` technically still applies only to the first `RewriteRule`. The original question does need backreferences.

Comment: I have mentioned this in the last sentence of my anwser, @rustyx. Still I think that many users who do not need back reference will read this posting and will enjoy the skip based solution.

Comment: @Jpsy Can any of the possibly skipped Rules have their own Conds? If so, does this affect what to set in the `S` parameter?

Comment: @JAAulde I guess not. I have never tried it, but the docs only talk about skipping RewriteRules, not Conds. But you should have a look at the new directives <If>, <Else>, <ElseIf>. They are available since Apache 2.4 and might solve your problem. See
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Comment: @Jpsy, thanks! Yeah, I want to use `<If>` but am on Apache 2.2 at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Clearly, this isn’t much fun, especially as things grow and become more complex. However, there is a less well known option of the RewriteRule statement, that tells apache to skip the next N number of RewriteRule statement. [S=N]. So instead of checking each time if the request is NOT a file AND is NOT a directory, we could do this:
Code block

```
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/$ http://www.santweb.co.uk/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^./]+)/$ http://www.santweb.co.uk/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^./]+)/([^./]+)/$ http://www.santweb.co.uk/$1/$2/$3 [L]
```

#

I found this, from: http://www.sant-media.co.uk/2010/03/applying-rewritecond-to-multiple-rewriterule-in-htaccess/

I think it helpfull

Comment: Yes not fun. Somebody should tell the folks at Apache about if/else blocks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From Apache 2.4 you can use the `<If>` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
<If "%{HTTP:Upgrade} == 'websocket'">
    RewriteRule /nidoran/(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/nidoran/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule /kakuna/(.*)           ws://localhost:8081/kakuna/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule /porygon/(.*)           ws://localhost:8082/porygon/$1 [P,L]
</If>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples