# Htaccess rewrites for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to put 2 seperate sites in subfoldres and use rewites to load them.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.udstde\.co\.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test1\.udstde\.co\.uk
RewriteRule (.*) /test1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.udstde\.co\.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test2\.udstde\.co\.uk
RewriteRule (.*) /test2/index.php [L]
```

The problem being the first one works fine but the second one doesn't.

Can anyone see where im going wrong?

Comment: You can use variables in apache Rewrite mode as
[Multiple RewriteRules for single RewriteCond in .htaccess][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218164/multiple-rewriterules-for-single-rewritecond-in-htaccess/11559655#11559655

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem, in your first set of conditions,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.udstde\.co\.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test1\.udstde\.co\.uk
```

whenever test2 comes up, above condition turns true as both conditions turn false. (i guess)

Comment: :-) cool. even though my answer is not entirely correct. i realise now. Anyways, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.udstde\.co\.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).udstde\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L]
```