# URL rewriting in htaccess rewrite condition and variable explanation

Tags: .htaccess

I am learning to create a REST api from a tutorial.
In the tutorial there was one step which performs URL rewriting. The code is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Can anybody please explain rewrite condition and `%{ENV:BASE}` part in it ?

Comment: `%{ENV:BASE}` would have been defined by one of the rules itself.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is simple:

If requested URI does not indicate to any existing file then redirect to `${ENV:BASE}index.php`.

You can find description of RewriteRule flags [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html). Briefly speaking:

`QSA` stands for "query string append". It means that query string will be appended to replacement URI.

`L` means that is the last rule and no further rules will be processed.

On [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html) there is a good explanation for environment variables in htaccess:

> The %{ENV:variable} form of TestString in the RewriteCond allows mod_rewrite's rewrite engine to make decisions conditional on environment variables. Note that the variables accessible in mod_rewrite without the ENV: prefix are not actually environment variables. Rather, they are variables special to mod_rewrite which cannot be accessed from other modules.

So, you can use environment variable in your rule like this `${ENV:<name>}`. The variable has to be set earlier, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`${ENV:<name>}` is used for avoiding repeated coding. Some conditions would be stored as variable and could be used in RewriteRules. For more details you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218164/multiple-rewriterules-for-single-rewritecond-in-htaccess).