# 301 redirects for wordpress multisite subdomains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, wpmu

I am having an issue that is very similar to the one described [here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/301-redirects-on-multisite-1), which was never resolved.

I have a WordPress Multisite install with subdomains and I'm trying to get the old URLs to redirect to the new ones.

Basically, I'm using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
```

to target each subdomain, with a batch of RewriteRules following.

Here is a small snippet of my code:

```
# Rewrite rules for French site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr.nomacorc.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ http://fr.nomacorc.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aboutus\.php$ http://fr.nomacorc.com/propos-de-nous/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ourclosures\.php$ http://fr.nomacorc.com/bouchons-pour-le-vin/ [R=301,NC,L]

# Rewrite rules for German site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de.nomacorc.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ http://de.nomacorc.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aboutus\.php$ http://de.nomacorc.com/uber-uns/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ourclosures\.php$ http://de.nomacorc.com/weinverschlusse/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

What I want to have happen is for de.nomacorc.com/aboutus.php to redirect to de.nomacorc.com/uber-uns, but instead it's redirecting to fr.nomacorc.com/propos-de-nous/. Same thing is happening with the ourclosures.php redirect.

What am I doing wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952074/2340759).

What I needed to do was link the group of RewriteRules to the above RewriteCond. The way to do that was describes really well:

> ```
> - Negate the condition (prepend it with !)
> - If you have multiple RewriteConds:
> - Change logical ANDs in the Conds to ORs and vice versa.
> - Add a skipping rewrite rule in front of all rules that you want to tie to the condition(s), set the S parameter to the number of Rule lines to be skipped.
> ```

So here is my corrected code:

```
# Rewrite rules for French site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^fr.nomacorc.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule .? - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ http://fr.nomacorc.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aboutus\.php$ http://fr.nomacorc.com/propos-de-nous/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ourclosures\.php$ http://fr.nomacorc.com/bouchons-pour-le-vin/ [R=301,NC,L]

# Rewrite rules for German site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^de.nomacorc.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule .? - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ http://de.nomacorc.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aboutus\.php$ http://de.nomacorc.com/uber-uns/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ourclosures\.php$ http://de.nomacorc.com/weinverschlusse/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

I hope this helps anyone else who  may have the same problem!