# CakePHP 3.x use htaccess to rewrite directories as pagination query params

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.6

I am upgrading a CakePHP 1.x project to CakePHP 3.x

The 1.x project has URLs that are published in places that we can not change, like books, so I need to rewrite the previous URLs to match the Pagination URLs in CakePHP 3.x

This is an example of the 1.x URLs

```
http://example.org/ledgers/index/1/2
http://example.org/ledgers/index/<page_int>/<tribe_id_int>
```

This is what the 3.x URLs look like

```
http://example.org/ledgers/index?page=1&tribe=2
```

I have tried this htaccess ruleset

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^ledgers/index/(\d)+/(\d)+$ /ledgers/index?page=$1&tribe=$2 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

And the output from

```
die(print_r($this->request->getQueryParams(), true));
```

is

```
Array()
```

---

I saw in another StackOverflow post to try and use

https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Which gave me

```
RewriteRule ^ledgers/index/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ledgers/index?page=$1&tribe=$2 [L]
```

but still the output from

```
die(print_r($this->request->getQueryParams(), true));
```

is

```
Array()
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule must be defined before the `^ index.php [L]` one, as it catches everything and your rule will never be reached. Specifically in your case, it must be placed even before the `RewriteCond` line, as conditions can only apply to a single rule. Look into using [**skipping rules**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952074/1392379) for a workaround.

And while rewriting the URL internally will work, ie you will be able to access the query parameters, leaving the URL unchanged may have negative side effects, for example `Router::url()` would produce:

```
/ledgers/index/1/2?page=1&tribe=2
```

instead of:

```
/ledgers/index?page=1&tribe=2
```

So you may want to consider issuing an actual redirect like this (note the optional closing slash, and the `+` *inside* the parentheses to match the whole number, not just the last digit):

```
RewriteRule ^ledgers/index/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ /ledgers/index?page=$1&tribe=$2 [NC,L,QSA,R=301]
```

That will externally redirect to the new URL structure, and using the `QSA` flag it also allows to merge in possible existing query params, ie:

```
/ledgers/index/1/2?foo=bar
```

would redirect to:

```
/ledgers/index?page=1&tribe=2&foo=bar
```

See also

- **[Apache Documentation > Version 2.4 > Modules > mod_rewrite > RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)**
- **[Apache Documentation > Version 2.4 > Rewrite > RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)**