# Apache, .htaccess, multiple index page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to a file which executed at EVERY request, lets say `index.php`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

however, if it happens to have `index2.php`, lets rather execute that file. In other words, if `index2.php` exists, it overrides the default behaviour. So I would write this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

but if `index2.php` doesnt exists, it fails

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

this way too. `Index2.php` doesnt need to be exists, but `index.php` does and will always be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition, and apply the `RewriteRule` only when index2.php exists.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index2.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: You should also add the `L` flag. Is `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index2.php` the correct path?

Comment: breaking: this applies to images, so the design is broken. Is there any way to define exceptions by file extension?

Comment: Commonly with those rules you usually want to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ( for both )

Comment: You can use the RewriteRule flag S|skip to tie multiples RewriteRules to a single RewriteCond. Otherwise you need to repeat the same `RewriteCond`s for both `RewriteRule`s.

Comment: sorry I cant make it work :S could you make a pastebin example for me?

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow morning, I'm on mobile right now; keep in mind this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520448/multiple-rewriterule-to-one-rewritecond

Comment: now the images works but for the root, I get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Comment: What you mean "for the root"? Is there an index page?

Comment: if I just visit the on localhost, without any URL parameters. The entryPont.php is available

Comment: Is there an index.php, index.html, ..., that the webserver doesn't have the permission to read?

Comment: no, there is no index.php, index.phtml and its Windows. You also used "entryPoint*.php" files

Comment: to summary up, the rules again. I want to have direct access to .png, .jpg, .gif, .jpeg, .bmp, .ico, .flv, .mpeg, .mp4, .mp3, .swf files. Any other case, site should look for entryPoint2.php and execute if exists. If not, execut entryPoint.php

Comment: Usually is more easy to say that with "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f", that's mean "only if the file requested doesn't exists". You can add another condition and exclude index.php